# git: commit without additional info (--quiet flag dont work)

Tags: git

I am writing bash script now.
Why this is not correct command?
How to combine usage of several flags?

```
git commit --quiet -m "-"
```

Comment: Do you mean `quiet` rather than `quite`?

Answer (score 2):

Either you've misspelled `--quiet`:

```
git commit --quiet -m "-"
```

or you need to use *one* hyphen to introduce a group of options. The following are equivalent:

```
git commit -q -u -i -t -e -m "-"
git commit -quite -m "-"
git commit -quitem "-"
```